# Can't check client certs in CherryPy (mTLS)

Tags: python, windows, ssl, cherrypy, mtls

Is mTLS possible on CherryPy 18.9 / Python 3.12 ?

The server is providing a valid certificate fine and clients are able to validate and connect to it via https without issue.

However, for this particular project, I need to be able to authenticate client certs, so am wondering if it's implemented or a known issue in CherryPy?  I have generated client certificates but do not know how to config cherrypy to demand them / make them obligatory - or if its possible?

```
cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.ssl_certificate_chain': 'ca.cert.pem',
    'server.ssl_verify_client': 'force',
    'server.ssl_verify_depth': 3
})
```

The above just allows any client in regardless.

Any help or ideas much appreciated :)

Comment: Which web server are you deploying? The settings you configured are not for configuring mTLS, those configure certificate verification for requests/connections from your system to another https endpoint.

Comment: Thanks John.  I am deploying CherryPy.  I want to validate client certs using my CA cert.  (I have generated client certs signed by my CA).  Snooping around I heard mention of using an SSLContext via pyopenssl (one of CherryPy's two ssl modules, builtin / pyopenssl) but info on validating clients this way appears sparse so I don't even know if its possible.

Comment: Deploy a web server such as Apache or Nginx in front of CherryPy. Then configure mTLS at the web server. I would not deploy CherryPy directly to the Internet.

Comment: Why not John?  What's wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have experience in public-facing Internet sites? Google search on why services like Apache and Nginx are recommended instead of exposing frameworks.

Comment: The only way to secure a Windows Server is to hide it behind Linux?  I appreciate you trying to push Linux but not everyone's on that train nor is the only way to serve content securely.  Thanks for the feedback.  If Nginx was so bulletproof then why do we have this: https://nginx.org/en/security_advisories.html

Comment: My comments have nothing to do with Linux. For example, Apache and Nginx run on Windows. Window Server includes IIS. How did you determine I am promoting Linux? Regarding your Nginx bug, every major software product has issues known and unknown. There are many options including running your app as a container on any OS. Your original question is mTLS + CherryPi. Since CherryPi does not support mTLS, you need to put a proxy in front of CherryPi to manage mTLS.